# ReflectionException in Route.php line 339: Class App\Http\Controllers\ContactRequest does not exist

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to achieve a contact form using Laravel Form Request so I created a request with code:

```
 class ContactRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

also have my route file correctly setup:

```
Route::get('contact',
['as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'AboutController@make']);
Route::post('contact',
['as' => 'contact_store', 'uses' => 'AboutController@store']);
```

But it keeps saying:

```
ReflectionException in Route.php line 339:
Class App\Http\Controllers\ContactRequest does not exist
```

Help please, what do I do?

Comment: In your **`AboutController`** check whether there is **`use App\Http\Requests\ContactRequest;`**

Comment: Thanks, that was missing.It works now. But it doesn't show the message in the form when it is submitted: return \Redirect::route('contact')
      ->with('message', 'Thanks for contacting us!');

Comment: Are you calling the variable in the view ?

Answer (score 1):

Add request class namespace to the top of the controller:

```
use App\Http\Requests\ContactRequest;
```

After that you'll be able to inject it using just it's class name:

```
public function store(ContactRequest $request)
```